# What does it mean 'OAuth is a protocol'?

Tags: oauth

What does it mean 'OAuth is a protocol'?

Is this some kind of abstract specification but not a concrete implementation?

So if I would like to use OAuth do I need an Identity and access management system like Oak, Keyloak or Ping Federate that supports OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean 'OAuth is a protocol'?

Ok i ask you what is a "protocol"? or actually what is a "communication Protocol", let's check wikipedia.

> A [communication protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol) is a system of rules that allow two or more entities of a communications system to transmit information via any kind of variation of a physical quantity.

In layman's terms protocol simply sets up some guidelines as to how requests should look.   The protocol for stack overflow is that everything is written in english, everyone understands that and most people use english.  Anyone using another language will be asked to translate it or it will be closed because it is against the protocol on stackoverflow.

Okay now "What is Oauth" again lets check Wikipedia.

> [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) is an open standard for access delegation, commonly used as a way for Internet users to grant websites or applications access to their information on other websites but without giving them the passwords.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol)

Prior to Oauth if you wanted to access private user data on an API you had to use something called client credentials.  which basically meant an application would the users send login and password along with the request.

Besides being a security nightmare (pre https) the issue with this is that if the user changes their password the call would then break the call unless the user remembered to submit a new password to the system using the api.

So oauth was born.  Its bacily a set of calls three or four typically. (Oauth2)

1. App builds link to the Auth server show to user which requests permission of the user.  Auth server returns permission to the application
2. Application takes that permission sends it to auth server see i have permission now give me access.
3. Server returns access

This is the Oauth protocol a list of requests agreed upon in [rfc Oauth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) that map out how user authorization can be granted between an application, an authorization server and a user.

So back to your question "What does it mean 'OAuth is a protocol'?"  This is the agreed upon Oauth protocol.   Its a set of steps used by applications and authorization servers to grant access to users data.

> Is this some kind of abstract specification but not a concrete implementation?

I think you should have a look at [rfc Oauth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

> So if I would like to use OAuth do I need an Identity and access management system like Oak, Keyloak or Ping Federate that supports OAuth?

I think you should check those systems on your own.